# Full width input within dynamic full width container left of fixed width item

Tags: css, flexbox

Sort of hard to explain in the title... but basically I need the item on the right (search button) to be of fixed width. The item on the left fills the rest of the space.

HTML:

```
<div class="ric-search-form">
  <button id="ricSearchButton">Search</button>
  <div class="ric-search-input-group"><span class="icon-search8"></span>
    <input style="" placeholder="Search" id="ricSearchField">
  </div>
</div>
```

Within the item on the left (`.rich-search-input-group`) there is a `span` and an `input`. How can I make sure that my `input` fills up the remaining of `.rich-search-input-group`?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oocncfvx/) demonstrating the issue.

You can see where the input ends if you hover and watch the cursor change or if you type to fill it out.

Comment: Why jsfiddle? Use inline snippets

Comment: @Amit - habit from before inline snippets, i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `display: flex;` to your `.ric-search-input-group` class, and give your `<input>` a `flex-grow: 1;`.

**CSS**

```
.ric-search-form .ric-search-input-group {
    display: flex;
}

.ric-search-form .ric-search-input-group input {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:white;
}
.ric-search-form {
    font-family: "Knowledge Regular";
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
}
.ric-search-form button {
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #ff8000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.ric-search-form .ric-search-input-group {
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: flex;
}
.ric-search-form .ric-search-input-group span {
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #c8c8c8;
}
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.ric-search-form .ric-search-input-group input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #9b9b9b;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ric-search-form">
  <button id="ricSearchButton">Search</button>
  <div class="ric-search-input-group"><span class="icon-search8"></span>
    <input style="" placeholder="Search" id="ricSearchField">
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oocncfvx/4/)**